# Question about the normal force acting on a toppling rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

I'm pondering a situation where a mass-less rod of with 2 balls of mass $m$ attached to either end of it is balanced on a friction-less surface. At a certain point the rod is slightly tipped and begins toppling. 
[image]

Now, the forces acting on the entire rod are obviously gravity and the normal force of the surface. My question is regarding the forces acting on each ball. At first I thought the forces acting on the top ball are only gravity and the normal force of the rod, while the forces acting on the bottom ball are the 2 above forces as well as the normal force of the surface, but this led to a paradoxical result when comparing the torque on the 2 objects (which should be identical from the frame of reference of the center of mass).

So does the surface normal force act also on the top ball? If so, is it a general statement that the normal force on an object acts on the entire object no matter what the points of contact are?

Comment: A diagram of the setup would significantly help in understanding the question.

Comment: Why do you want the net torque to be $0$? Or as you said, equal.

Comment: @FakeMod Well from the frame of reference of the center of mass the objects remain at the same distance from the origin, have the same mass and move with the same (instantaneous) angular velocity, so the torque on each ball must be equal to my understanding.

Comment: The center of mass itself is accelerating, so it's no longer an inertial fram and thus you would have to apply a pseudo torque which would then equalize the initiall different torques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rods, unlike strings, can exert both a force *along* the rod and forces *transverse* to the rod. You can wave a mass on a rod around, pushing it side to side.

For example, if you had this rod fixed in the middle, you could push on one mass and the other one would rotate too.

Answer (score 0):

The normal force at the lower surface breaks into two components. One parallel to the rod matches the compression in the rod.  The other produces a CCW torque about the center of mass.  The compression has a horizontal component which accelerates the lower mass to the right (and the upper mass to the left).  Gravity at the upper mass also has two components.  One matching the compression, and the other also producing a CCW torque about the center of mass.  There is no reason to assume hat these two torques are equal. Since there is no net external horizontal force, the center of mass must accelerate straight down.  (Gravity on the left exceeds the net vertical force on the right.)  If you let your masses be of finite size, then each requires a torque to produce it angular acceleration.  This requires an additional force acting perpendicular to the opposite end of the rod for each.

Answer (score 0):

The object is a rigid body which maintains a fixed shape. You can ignore the complications of the internal forces in the rod (tension/compression and bending moments) and instead consider only the effect of external forces. These cause an acceleration of the CM of the rigid body and a rotational acceleration about the CM.